# Area51 missing associated accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, linked-accounts

I've recently created my account on Area51, and as usually automatically associated accounts. I've committed to [one of the proposals](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language-usage), but in the information about my commitment information about most of my accounts (and most of my rep) is missing.
[image]

Compare above image with my actual network profile: https://stackexchange.com/users/a21211b1-9347-490a-9192-45009649a8cc?tab=accounts or stackfair

[image]

Comment: What is weird is that it should show the first six SE sites where your reputation is higher.

Comment: @kia: exactly, and it should show around 40k total rep

Comment: It seems that random SE sites have been picked up; the second SE shown site should not even appear, as the flair itself shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed now.

Our code responsible for aggregating and saving this information was timing out (so many users now...). It's been re-written, so your A51 *user card* looks correct now.

Comment: I'm experiencing this exact same problem. Area51 claims no linked accounts with >200 reputation when I have at least two of them.

Comment: @David your A51 user info looks correct to me.. where is it claiming no linked accounts with >=200 rep?

Comment: It repaired itself. I think it was just the fact that it only updates daily. Thanks for looking into it.